# How to place button in the center?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I use [twitter bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/) and its [cover](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/) example as the base. I added a few input fields there and would like to have second (`email`) to be located in the middle (i.e. horizontally aligned). I've tried to add `.center-block` and `.text-center` to different `div` elements, but it didn't help. What should be the solution?

Here is the code:

```
  <p class="lead">Some other text to demonstrate something else</p>
  <div class="lead">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="text-center center-text">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" id="analyze" data-loading-text="Wait...">Analyze</button>
  </div>
```

and here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/qv3r21hc/1/).

Answer (score 0):

remove class input-group like below:

```
<div class="input-group-lg">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fwz0w44n/

Comment: Thanks, but it changes the width of button, how should I keep it unchanged?

Comment: you must change the inner divs of your "form-control", as shown: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pqek76qo/